# meaning of "All of them had collected"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this sentence:

> All of them had collected 100 different comics as of 31 July 2014.

Does this mean each one of them individually had collected 100? Or that they had done so as an aggregate?

Comment: The answer is yes. (It could be either one.)

Answer (score 1):

Sentences like these are ambiguous. Normally you would ask for clarification by asking if the speaker meant 100 comics each, or 100 comics combined.